# Cannot view website on internet, IIS SVN problem

Tags: iis, windows-xp, svn, router

I have a server set up with SVN and IIS.  I have opened the ports for IIS and SVN in my router and am able to connect to the SVN server with SSL.  But for some reason I am unable to connect to the IIS website.  I have tried over and over again checking the settings and opening up ports, I eventually just enabled the DMZ and was still unable to get to it.  I can however access it over the local network.  I have a linksys router with DD-WRT installed.  Can anyone think of what I am missing?!  Also, I have made sure that the SVN and IIS servers don't interfere with each other and they are running on the same machine, it is an xp machine.

Details Update: They are both on the same machine, IIS is using port 80 and 443, while SVN is using 8443.  In the router I have the ports forwarded like so, 80 to 80 for html from IIS, and 443 and 8443 to 8443.  As mentioned before on the local network I can reach both servers.  On the web I can only reach the SVN, that is why I believe it has to do with the router.

Comment: Can you clarify how they are set up?  Do you have them on separate IP's, different ports?  Typically SVN uses standard HTTP ports, 80 and 443, but IIS and SVN cannot be listening on the same IP/port combo so how do you have that partitioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, after checking everything over and over again, I decided to search all ports on my ip range.  And after doing so I noticed there was not one single one with port 80 opened.  Was my ISP doing this?  After a simple google search, I found the answer is yes.  My ISP is blocking port 80.  Now my question turns to, why?